# How to use writeChartAsPNG in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jfreechart

Can anyone explain how to use `writeChartAsPNG` in JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check this link out.Its good.

[How to use writeChartAsPNG](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-return-a-dynamically-generated-pie-chart-from-a-servlet.html)

They have used `ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG()` methods in the example given over there.

Answer (score 1):

`<img src="/path/to/chart" />` and have this path handled by a servlet, where:

```
ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPng(response.getOutputStream(), ....);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not totally related, but you might also consider Cewolf (http://cewolf.sourceforge.net/new/), which provides a JSP tag-library on top of JFrechart, and thus liberates you from using JSP scriplets.