# jfree chart savechartaspng utility not getting new chart

Tags: jfreechart

i am using jfree chart to generate pie chart dynamically, but i have problem. When i need to show output on IE6, the chart is not getting refreshed. i need to close the and reopen the browser and then input new value

*Can anyone suggest what could be solution for the above problem?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use writeChartAsPNG in JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496411/how-to-use-writechartaspng-in-jsp)

Comment: That one specifies how to write it initially, which the OP seems to have accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are having caching issues. I assume your chart is loaded from an image tag. If the address for the image tag is the same then IE will cache the image to speed up future loads. There are several general methods to prevent this.

[how to clear or replace a cached image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321865/how-to-clear-or-replace-a-cached-image)

[Disable cache for some images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images/729623#729623)

*Also note that the image won't change without some type of new request, be it a page refresh or some type of AJAX polling. [W3 Schools Info](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp)*