# Generate image and display it inside JSP along with other content in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, jfreechart, jfreereport

I'm using JFreeChart to generate a dynamic chart depending on some data thet is coming from databse. I have a JSP with  one combobox, the user makes the input and submits it, and the Action process it, generating an image of a chart. 
I need to display this image on the same JSP as before, below the combobox.but it is only graph image coming on page.how can i make it on same page?

I'm using spring on my webapp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use JavaScript. When the form is submitted, intercept the submission by a JavaScript event handler, and then simply insert an `<img>` tag in the page, where you want the graph to appear. This image should have the URL of the action generating the graph.

With jQuery, it would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function() {
        var url = '/actionWhichGeneratesTheGraph?selection=' + $('#theSelectBox').val();
        $('#theDivWhereTheGraphMustAppear').html('<img src="' + url + '"/>');
        return false;
    });
});
```

If the graph changes each time it's generated, even for a similar selection, you should add some random parameter at the end of the URL to prevent browser caching.

Comment: using javascript how can i do??

Comment: The URL that generates the chart can refer to a servlet, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5496411/230513).